# JSON encode unicode issue on PHP5.3

Tags: php, json, joomla2.5

a string in hebrew after json_encode looks like this:
[{"id":"1","value":"\u05d1\u05dc\u05d0\u05d2\u05df"}
any Idea what encoding is this and how do I get this to either work or be readable again?
BTW, this is a Joomla system which runs on PHP 5.3, string is from post request, not a database and UTF-8 meta tag do exist.

Comment: That looks like unicode.

Comment: Maybe you can use base64 to encode your string, and decode it when needed

Comment: it's normal, you can use it and you will get normal data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how JSON encodes non-ASCII characters. The text will be readable again when you pass it through a **JSON  parser**.

PHP 5.4 defines a new option for `json_encode`, `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, that would pass UTF-8 text through as-is without converting it to escape codes. Since you are using PHP 5.3 you can't use it, but if you had 5.4 this is how it would be used:

```
$json = json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); // PHP 5.4 required
```

However, this should not be needed because the JSON parser will decode the escape codes.

Comment: Thanks anyway, this actually has been a lot of help!
the text is readable after decoding and it seems that my problem was actually that slashes were disapearing upon entering the database.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$encoded = json_encode($json);

$unescaped = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', function ($matches) {
            return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
        }, $encoded);

file_put_contents('sample.json', $unescaped);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).